# vim - search for string at start of line, then delete last 3 characters on line above

Tags: search, vim

I would like to search a file for a string which occurs at the start of a line,
then delete the last 3 characters on the line above.

So in the example below I wish to search for "result select" then on the line above delete the 2 spaces followed by a backwards slash

```
  0.9546  \
  1.2356  \
result select bla bla
result case bla bla
```

Would become,

```
  0.9546  \
  1.2356
result select bla bla
result case bla bla
```

Many thanks,

Comment: `:%s/  \\\n\(result select\)/\r\1/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This searches for, and erases, any three characters which are followed by an EOL then the word 'result select'.

```
%s/...\(\nresult select\)\@=//c
```

Just to explain things a little...

`...` matches any three three non EOL characters.  If you want to handle lines shorter than three characters, you could use `.\{,3\}` instead, for `%s/.\{,3\}\(\nresult select\)\@=//c`.

`\(\nresult select\)` just takes `\nresult select` and puts it into a single atom so we can use it with lookahead matching.

`\@=` tells vim to look for, but do not include in the matched results, the previous atom.  So we are only looking for matches followed by a newline and 'result select'

`//` replaces the matched string with nothing.

`c` just forces the user manually to confirm each replace since this regex is so weird it might do bad things.

Answer (score 2):

Use a global command to search for the line. Then on the previous line remove the last two spaces and a `\` that appear at the end of the line.

```
:g/^result/-1s/  \\$//
```

The previous line is found by using `-1` for the range of the substitute command.